# Juego Craps en Java

Tags: java, array

Si alguien conoce el juego de azar con dados Craps, y lo estoy haciendo en Java, quizas puedan ayudarme con un problema que tengo en el codigo.

Este juego es muy facil, y consiste en arrojar la suma de 2 dados, y su suma, si es 7 u 11 ganas la partida. En cambio, si sacas un 2, 3 o 12 pierdes.

Ahora con cualquier otro numero que saques, ese numero se convierte en un "punto", en el cual, si con otra tirada de dados sacas ese numero ganas, y si sacas un 7 pierdes la partida.
Estoy realizando este juego con array (que guarda en las posiciones 0 y 1 los resultados) para realizar una estadística de entre 10.000 de juegos, la cantidad de jugadas ganadas y perdidas, y con cuantas cantidad de tiros puedo perder o ganar. Estoy usando la clase SecureRandom aleatorios para los dados.

Ahora el problema, es que de acuerdo a mi código no me esta imprimiendo la frecuencia de tiros, ya que de 1 a 5 tiros tanto en partida ganada o perdida es una estadística que sirve para el analisis del juego.

Este ejercicio fue propuesto en el capitulo 7.18 del libro de Deitel.
Alguien podría ayudarme a sacar la frecuencia de tiros del 1 al 5 y del 6 en adelante tanto en partidas ganadas, como perdidas? No entiendo que estoy haciendo mal!
Mil gracias

he modificado mi código, y de acuerdo a los resultados de las partidas este seria el código resultante:

```
package Capitulo7;

import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.lang.model.type.ArrayType;

public class JuegoCraps718 {

private static final SecureRandom aleatorios = new SecureRandom();
private static final int CANTIDAD_JUEGOS = 5;
private static int[] arrayGanadores = new int[2];
private static int[] arrayPerdedores = new int[2];
private static int frecuencia;
private static final int LIMITE_TIROS = 2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (int i = 0; i < CANTIDAD_JUEGOS; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        frecuencia = 0;
        tiros(tirarDados());
    }
    imprimir();
}

public static int tirarDados() {
    frecuencia++;
    int dado1 = 1 + aleatorios.nextInt(6);
    int dado2 = 1 + aleatorios.nextInt(6);
    int total = dado1 + dado2;
    return total;
}

public static void tiros(int total) {
    if (total == 7 || total == 11) {
        System.out.println("Gano en primera vuelta con un =" + total + " y una frecucia de = " + frecuencia);
        contarFrecuenciaGanadora();
    } else if (total == 2 || total == 3 || total == 12) {
        System.out.println("Perdio en primera vuelta con un =" + total + " y una frecucia de = " + frecuencia);
        contarFrecuenciaPerdedora();
    } else
        puntoYSiete(total);

}

public static void puntoYSiete(int punto) {
    int totalNuevaTirada = tirarDados();
    if (totalNuevaTirada != 7) {
        if (totalNuevaTirada == punto) {
            System.out.println("Gano con un punto de = " + punto + " y una nueva tirada de = " + totalNuevaTirada
                    + " y una frecuencia de = " + frecuencia);
            contarFrecuenciaGanadora();

        } else {
            puntoYSiete(punto);

        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Perdio con un punto de = " + punto + " y una nueva tirada de = " + totalNuevaTirada
                + " y una frecuencia de = " + frecuencia);
        contarFrecuenciaPerdedora();

    }

}

private static void contarFrecuenciaPerdedora() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (frecuencia <= LIMITE_TIROS)
        arrayPerdedores[0]++;
    else
        arrayPerdedores[1]++;

}

private static void contarFrecuenciaGanadora() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (frecuencia <= LIMITE_TIROS)
        arrayGanadores[0]++;
    else
        arrayGanadores[1]++;

}

public static void imprimir() {
    System.out.println("Resultados de Juego Craps" + "\n");
    System.out.println("Frecuencia de ganadores del 1 al 5 tiros: " + arrayGanadores[0]);
    System.out.println("Frecuencia de perdedores del 1 al 5 tiros: " + arrayPerdedores[0]);
    System.out.println("Frecuencia de ganadores de mas de 5 tiros: " + arrayGanadores[1]);
    System.out.println("Frecuencia de perdedores de mas de 5 tiros: " + arrayPerdedores[1]);

}
}
```

Comment: Podria definir más a detalle que es la frecuencia

Comment: Si, la frecuencia serian la cantidad de tiros que tiene  una partida para finalizar. Si en primera mano la suma de los dados, no es 7 u 11 (partida ganada) o 2,3 o 12 (partida perdida), el jugador debe tener que tirar nuevamente (frecuencia suma 1 unidad) para poder igualar el "punto", es decir el numero que le salio en el primer tiro, hasta poder sacar el mismo (partida ganada) o sacar un 7 (partida perdida). La frecuencia debe sumar la cantidad de tiros que se hacen, hasta ganar o perder la partida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Solución 1

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class JuegoTiraDados {

    private static final SecureRandom aleatorios = new SecureRandom();
    private static final int CANTIDAD_JUEGOS = 10;
    private static int[] arrayGanadores = new int[2];
    private static int[] arrayPerdedores = new int[2];
    private static int frecGanadores;
    private static int frecPerdedores;
    private static final int LIMITE_PARTIDAS_CONSECUT = 1;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        frecGanadores =0;
        frecPerdedores =0;
        for (int i = 0; i < CANTIDAD_JUEGOS; i++) {
                tiros(tirarDados());
        }
        imprimir();
    }

    public static int tirarDados() {
        int dado1 = 1 + aleatorios.nextInt(6);
        int dado2 = 1 + aleatorios.nextInt(6);
        int total = dado1 + dado2;
        return total;
    }
    // a este método le pasamos como parametro el método tirarDados().
    // A su vez también le pasamos al método punto(int total) esa misma variable (total), ya que tiene que evaluar
    // si es igual a la nueva tirada
    public static void tiros(int total) {
        System.out.println("=== TIROS ===");
        System.out.println("total: "+total);
        System.out.println("frecuencia ganadores: "+frecGanadores);
        System.out.println("frecuencia perdedores: "+frecPerdedores);
        if (total == 7 || total == 11) {

            frecPerdedores =0;//tiene que reiniciar perdedores
            incrementGanadores();

        } else if (total == 2 || total == 3 || total == 12) {

            frecGanadores =0;//tiene q reiniciar ganadores
            incrementPerdedores();

        } else {
            punto(total);
        }
        System.out.println("frecuencia ganadores: "+frecGanadores);
        System.out.println("frecuencia perdedores: "+frecPerdedores);
        System.out.println("=== FIN TIROS ===");
    }

    public static void punto(int total) {
        System.out.println("=== PUNTO ===");

        int totalNuevaTirada =tirarDados();

        System.out.println("total: "+total);
        System.out.println("total nueva tirada: "+totalNuevaTirada);

        if(totalNuevaTirada != 7) {
            if (totalNuevaTirada == total) {

                frecPerdedores =0;//tiene que reiniciar perdedores
                incrementGanadores();

            }
            else
            {
                frecGanadores =0;//tiene q reiniciar ganadores
                incrementPerdedores();

            }
        }
        else
        {   
            frecGanadores =0;//tiene q reiniciar ganadores
            incrementPerdedores();

        }
        System.out.println("frecuencia ganadores: "+frecGanadores);
        System.out.println("frecuencia perdedores: "+frecPerdedores);
        System.out.println("=== FIN PUNTO ===");

    }
    private static void incrementGanadores(){
        if (frecGanadores < LIMITE_PARTIDAS_CONSECUT){
            arrayGanadores[0]++;
            frecGanadores++;
        }
        else
        {
            arrayGanadores[1]++;
            frecGanadores =0;
        }
    }
    private static void incrementPerdedores(){
        if (frecPerdedores < LIMITE_PARTIDAS_CONSECUT){
            arrayPerdedores[0]++;
            frecPerdedores++;
        }
        else
        {
            arrayPerdedores[1]++;
            frecPerdedores =0;
        }
    }

    public static void imprimir() {

        System.out.println("Resultados de Juego Craps:");

        if(LIMITE_PARTIDAS_CONSECUT == 1){
            System.out.println("Frecuencia de ganadores en la 1º partida: " + arrayGanadores[0]);
            System.out.println("Frecuencia de perdedores en la 1º partida: " + arrayPerdedores[0]);
            System.out.println("Frecuencia de ganadores que alcanzaron 2 partidas consecutivas: " + arrayGanadores[1]);
            System.out.println("Frecuencia de perdedores que alcanzaron 2 partidas consecutivas: " + arrayPerdedores[1]);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Frecuencia de ganadores de la 1º a la "+LIMITE_PARTIDAS_CONSECUT+"º partida: " + arrayGanadores[0]);
            System.out.println("Frecuencia de perdedores de la 1º a la "+LIMITE_PARTIDAS_CONSECUT+"º partida: " + arrayPerdedores[0]);
            System.out.println("Frecuencia de ganadores que alcanzaron las "+LIMITE_PARTIDAS_CONSECUT+" partidas consecutivas: " + arrayGanadores[1]);
            System.out.println("Frecuencia de perdedores que alcanzaron las "+LIMITE_PARTIDAS_CONSECUT+" partidas consecutivas: " + arrayPerdedores[1]);
        }
    }    
}
```

- Solución 2 (con ArrayList de Boolean)

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JuegoTiraDados2 {
    private static final SecureRandom aleatorios = new SecureRandom();
    private static final int CANTIDAD_JUEGOS = 10;
    private static List<Boolean> ganadores;
    private static List<Boolean> perdedores;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ganadores =new ArrayList<>();//inicializamos los ArrayList
        perdedores =new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < CANTIDAD_JUEGOS; i++) {
                tiros(tirarDados());
        }
        imprimirTotalResultados();
    }
    public static int tirarDados() {
        int dado1 = 1 + aleatorios.nextInt(6);
        int dado2 = 1 + aleatorios.nextInt(6);
        int total = dado1 + dado2;
        return total;
    }
    // a este método le pasamos como parametro el método tirarDados().
    // A su vez también le pasamos al método punto(int total) esa misma variable (total), ya que tiene que evaluar
    // si es igual a la nueva tirada
    public static void tiros(int total) {
        System.out.println("=== TIROS ===");
        System.out.println("total: "+total);
        System.out.println("ganadores: "+ganadores);
        System.out.println("perdedores: "+perdedores);

        if (total == 7 || total == 11){
            ganadores.add(Boolean.TRUE);
            perdedores.add(Boolean.FALSE);
        }
        else if (total == 2 || total == 3 || total == 12){
            perdedores.add(Boolean.TRUE);
            ganadores.add(Boolean.FALSE);
        }
        else punto(total);

        System.out.println("ganadores: "+ganadores);
        System.out.println("perdedores: "+perdedores);
        System.out.println("=== FIN TIROS ===");
    }

    public static void punto(int total) {
        System.out.println("=== PUNTO ===");

        int totalNuevaTirada =tirarDados();

        System.out.println("total: "+total);
        System.out.println("total nueva tirada: "+totalNuevaTirada);

        if(totalNuevaTirada != 7) {
            if (totalNuevaTirada == total){
                ganadores.add(Boolean.TRUE);
                perdedores.add(Boolean.FALSE);
            }
            else{
                perdedores.add(Boolean.TRUE);
                ganadores.add(Boolean.FALSE);
            }
        }
        else{
            perdedores.add(Boolean.TRUE);
            ganadores.add(Boolean.FALSE);
        }

        System.out.println("ganadores: "+ganadores);
        System.out.println("perdedores: "+perdedores);
        System.out.println("=== FIN PUNTO ===");

    }
    public static int totalGanadores(){
        int cont =0;
        // recorremos lista contando los que tienen valor verdadero
        for(Boolean b:ganadores)
            if(b.booleanValue() == true) cont++;
        return cont;
    }
    public static int totalPerdedores(){
        int cont =0;
        for(Boolean b:perdedores)
            if(b.booleanValue() == true) cont++;
        return cont;
    }
    /**
     * Devuelve la frecuencia de partidas ganadas consecutivamente iguales al
     * valor pasado por parámetro
     * @param partidasConsecut Número de partidas ganadas consecutivas a evaluar
     * @return <ul>
     * <li>valor > 0: si encuentra al menos una coincidencia </li>
     * <li>valor = 0: si no encuentra ninguna</li>
     * </ul>
     */
    public static int ganadoresPartidasConsecutivas(int partidasConsecut){
        int contTemporal =0;
        int cont =0;
        for(Boolean b:ganadores){
            if(b.booleanValue() == true) contTemporal++;
            else contTemporal =0;//reiniciamos por que ya no se cumple la regla de consecutivos
            if(contTemporal == partidasConsecut){
                cont++;
                contTemporal =0;//hay que reiniciar para comenzar nuevamente el conteo
            }
        }
        return cont;
    }
    /**
     * Devuelve la frecuencia de partidas perdidas consecutivamente iguales al
     * valor pasado por parámetro
     * @param partidasConsecut Número de partidas perdidas consecutivas a evaluar
     * @return <ul>
     * <li>valor > 0: si encuentra al menos una coincidencia </li>
     * <li>valor = 0: si no encuentra ninguna</li>
     * </ul>
     */
    public static int perdedoresPartidasConsecutivas(int partidasConsecut){
        // Fijate que para hacer este método solo bastó reemplazar ganadores por perdedores
        int contTemporal =0;
        int cont =0;
        for(Boolean b:perdedores){
            if(b.booleanValue() == true) contTemporal++;
            else contTemporal =0;
            if(contTemporal == partidasConsecut){
                cont++;
                contTemporal =0;
            }
        }
        return cont;
    }
    public static void imprimirTotalResultados() {

        System.out.println("**** Resultados de Juego Craps ****\n");
        System.out.println("Lista completa de partidas");
        System.out.println("Ganadores:");
        System.out.println(ganadores);
        System.out.println("Perdedores:");
        System.out.println(perdedores);
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Total ganadores: "+totalGanadores());
        System.out.println("Total perdedores: "+totalPerdedores());
        System.out.println("Total ganadores de 3 partidas consecutivas: "+ganadoresPartidasConsecutivas(3));
        System.out.println("Total perdedores de 3 partidas consecutivas: "+perdedoresPartidasConsecutivas(3));
    }
}
```

Nota: los `System.out.println("texto")` son para hacer el seguimiento y ver como funciona

Comment: Hola @Juan Rom, como estas? Disculpa la demora de tu respuesta, veo que el codigo esta muy bien, sin embargo, hice la prueba en modificar LIMITE_TIROS=1, y no se si es un error en tu codigo, pero la mayoria de las partidas ganadas salen en el primer tiro, donde estadisticamente, el 50% de las partidas se resuelven en mas de un tiro. Prueba el  codigo. mil gracias

Comment: Hola Gonzalo, ahí me fijo. Pero si, no hay problema, vos decime que es lo que no funciona bien, ya que no pude probarlo muy bien

Comment: Bueno el error estaba en los métodos incrementar: reemplacé esto: `if (frecPerdedores <= LIMITE_PARTIDAS_CONSECUT)` por esto: `if (frecPerdedores < LIMITE_PARTIDAS_CONSECUT)`. Ahí edito el código. Fijate que cambié el nombre `LIMITE_TIROS` por `LIMITE_PARTIDAS_CONSECUT` para que sea mas representativo, y además a `CANTIDAD_JUEGOS` lo dejé en valor `10` para que sea mas facil de sacar la estadística además de hacer el seguimiento o prueba de escritorio. Igualmente probalo y decime si hay que modificar algo mas

Comment: Voy a revisarlo @Juan Rom! Gracias

Comment: Fijate que edité el método `imprimir()`.Observa que reemplacé "..con mas de x partidas consecutivas" por "..que alcanzaron las x partidas consecutivas", ya que una vez que alcanza `LIMITE_PARTIDAS_CONSECUT` se reinicia la frecuencia. Si necesitas calcular  "..con mas de x partidas consecutivas", esta solución no lo contempla y hay que hacerlo de otra forma

Comment: Funciona excelente! Gracias!

Comment: Edito nuevamente para agregar una segunda solución interesante